# Display an item every second using a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently working on a Rails project, and I'm trying to make a loop inside my HTML file.

`@h` is a hash I created in my controller.

```
<% for @i in 0..954 do %>
    <% if @h[@i.to_s] != nil%>
            <%= render 'static_pages/home_data' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This code works and displays the elements I want.

Thing is, I want it to be displayed every second. I tried to put a `<% sleep 1 %>` but as predicted, it doesn't work like that...

Is there any way to do that directly in my HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Nice start. Couple of things though. Firstly rubyists generally won't use for loops in the way you have. Ruby is great with handing closure so each is a much more idiomatic expression.

```
<% [0..954].each do |index| %>
```

Secondly I would not have a variable called @h. What is h? Would another programmer be able to read your code and understand what @h is?

Thirdly ruby provides a .nil? method so you can do something like

```
<% if @h[index].nil? %>
```

However all of these won't help you get what you need done. What you seem to want to do is control the way elements display on your page. As I understand you want elements to display one at a time.

Sleeping won't help. Rails will firstly render a full page on the server. Once it has finished rendering it will send the rendered output back to the client. This happens via HTTP. The client won't even see the response until the entire template is rendered. Sleeping on the server will not change the way the client will see the output it will just make the response slower. You should never sleep on the server like this. Instead you will need to render the response as you would any other rails template and use javascript to control the way elements are displayed on the client.

Comment: Let me know if you would like to expand the answer at all.

Comment: Actually it was mostly to start testing some things.
Now I refresh a portion of my page every second with ajax, works better for my case ! But thank anyway :D

Comment: Great. Glad the answer was what you where looking for